# "Would have" usage

Tags: modal-verbs

I'm asking for clarification on the following sentences. How do their senses differ?

> 1. She did not become a doctor in a day – she had to put in a lot of hard work to make her dream come true.
> 2. She did not become a doctor in a day – she would have had to  put in a lot of hard work to make her dream come true.
> 3. She did not become a doctor in a day – she must have put in a lot of hard work to make her dream come true.

Answer (score 2):

Sentence (1) is given as a veridical statement, a matter of indisputable fact. It is given by someone who was close to the subject ('She') referent, who knows the facts (or is otherwise entirely convinced).

Sentence (3) uses a modal (which in the 'meaning' sense means 'adding an assessment of the likelihood of the veracity of the accompanying statement') construction. 'Must' implies (near) certainty in one usage, but can also be a sign that the speaker is fairly sure and trying to convince *themself*. In such a usage, it would be stressed in speech.

Sentence (2) also uses a modal construction. 'To succeed, you would have to ...' / 'As she succeeded, she would have had to ...'. I've listed it third rather than second, as I feel 'must' is generally higher up the 'I consider it probable that ...' scale.

.............

(1) **have to** [idiom] — used to say that something is required or necessary [[Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/have%20to)]

(3) **must** 4: be logically inferred //// 6: was or were presumably certain to [[Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/must)]

(2) **would** 4: — used in auxiliary function to express probability or presumption in past or present time [[Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/would)]

Comment: Thanks @Edwin it really helped.